# JAGS: multivariate normal with both, unobservable and observable variables?

Tags: jags, notation

I have a "simple" problem with JAGS that drives me crazy. In essence, consider the following example **that works**:

```
x2[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i,1], tau1);
u[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i,2], tau2);
```

Here, **x2 is an observable variable (that is, data), while u is a latent variable**. In the example, both are drawn independently from two distinct normal distributions.
However, I want them to be (possibly) dependent, that is, to be drawn from one multivariate normal distribution. So I would like to do:

```
c(x2[i], u[i]) ~ dmnorm(mu[i,1:2], Omega[1:2,1:2]);
```

Unfortunately, this **doesn't work** because this syntax is not correct. However, having tried many different syntaxes, neither of them does work. E.g.,

```
y[i,1] <- x2[i];
y[i,2] <- u[i];
y[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(mu[i,1:2], Omega[1:2,1:2]);
```

leads to the error *Node y[1,1:2] overlaps previously defined nodes*, what is obvious.
So what can I do? Please, help me, I'm getting mad...

UPDATE: I figured out that I can at least do the following:
(in R:)

```
p <- 1/(1+exp(-x2));
t <- rep(10000, length(x2));
s <- rbinom(length(x2), t, p2);
```

(in JAGS:)

```
nul[i,1] <- 0;
nul[i,2] <- 0;
e[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(nul[i,1:2], Omega[1:2,1:2]);
u[i] <- mu[i,2] + e[i,2];
x2g[i] <- mu[i,1] + e[i,1];
pg[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-x2g[i]));
s[i] ~ dbin(pg[i], t[i]);
```

This works (a bit), but looses of course efficiency since an observable variable (x2) is treated as if it was only indirectly observable (through s).

Answer (score 0):

You are defining y twice  Once in:

```
y[i,1] <- x2[i];
y[i,2] <- u[i];
```

And once in

```
y[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(mu[i,1:2], Omega[1:2,1:2]);
```

You might be able to get away with:

```
x2[i] <- y[i,1];
```

Or you might be able to simply write out the regression (after all it is bivariate, so not that difficulty).

You also might get a faster response on the JAGS mailing list (which Martyn Plummer regularly monitors).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data` block as follows:

```
data{
    for(i in 1:length(x2)) {
        y[i,1] <- x2[i]
        y[i,2] <- u[i]
    }
}
model{
    for(i in 1:length(x2)) {
        y[i,1:2] ~ dmnorm(mu[i,], Tau)
    }
    # ... definition of mu, Tau, and their prior distribution
}
```

However, be sure there are no missing values in `x2` or `u`, since a multivariate node cannot be partly observed.

Regards! :)